# Windows Explorer Column View not displaying Summary Information

Tags: vb.net, pdf, adobe, windows-explorer

Adobe PDF does not have summary information written as an OLE property set into a stream named "\005SummaryInformation" off the root storage.  It uses another method that Microsoft stopped supporting in XP.

Using DSOFile I have added Summary Information to a PDF.  This works...or at least I assmume so as after closing and opening the file the Summary Information is visible (Using a DSOFile viewer not Adobe)!

This is a simplified version of the code to save Summary Information to the PDF.  Note this will not work on all documents for example Office 2007 docs.  I use WindowsAPICodePack.dll for docs that this does not work on!

```
Dim oDocument As DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties = New DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties
oDocument.Open(FileName, False, DSOFile.dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionOpenReadOnlyIfNoWriteAccess)
Dim oSummProps As DSOFile.SummaryProperties = oDocument.SummaryProperties
If (NewData <> oSummProps.Title) Then
  oSummProps.Title = NewData
End If
oDocument.Save()
oDocument.Close()
```

My problem is the PDF Summary Information is not visible in Windows Explorer Columns.  The info I wish to see is System.Keywords (Tags) and System.Title.

Answer (score 1):

PDF files are not structured storage files so they cannot contain the \005SummaryInformation stream. I do not know how the code above works, but while it might insert a \005SummaryInformation stream in the PDF file, I'm pretty sure that it damages the PDF file.

Comment: For Summary Info Office products use _OLE property set as specified in [MS-OLEPS], GUID FMTID_SummaryInformation in doc stream "\005SummaryInformation"._  

PDF files can have metadata, "Document Information Dictionary" and "Extensible Metadata Platform (XMP)".  

Using DSOFile metadata has been added "somewhere" to the .PDF document albeit not as per Microsoft requirements.  The data is there somewhere and has not corrupted the .PDF.  Using VB.Net I need to add the info so Windows Explorer makes use of the Summary Information.  
Does anyone know **definatively** if this can be acomplished?

Comment: If you can post the file somewhere for download, I can take a look at it and tell you exactly where that metadata has been added. If the file can be opened with Adobe Reader after processing with the code above it does not mean it is not damaged, Adobe Reader repairs automatically many errors. Windows Explorer does not know anything about Document Information Dictionary or XMP metadata and PDF files do not support the OLE SummaryInformation stream. A possible solution would be to write a plugin for Windows Explorer that can handle PDF files and extract the metadata from them.